# Stop contents from overflowing and auto sizing to text expansion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview, material-ui

Sorry for long post, but it isn't long. But only looks long due to images.

I wanted to make layout like below:

[image]

So I wrote a layout for it as under

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:id="@+id/stock_item_image_small"/>

                <!-- Arrow at the end of the fragment item -->
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_18dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And this is visible as below
[image]

I then added a long string with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:id="@+id/stock_item_image_small"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:text="A line to string which is long enough to overflow our of container"/>

                <!-- Arrow at the end of the fragment item -->
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_18dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And it now looks like below.

[image]

As you can see, the arrow at the end, which was visible prior to adding a `TextView` has now overflown out of the view and is not visible.

**I basically want to know how can we add components one after another and they don't flow out of the view
How can I fix this ?**

Also, can someone **suggest a good material to for Layouts or begining with Android layout design ?**

---

**UPDATE:**

I incorporated the suggestions of [Ichvandi Octa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62370025/3722884), and wrote below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <!-- Added to create border around frame -->
    <!-- Achieved using corner radius and padding -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:contentPadding="1dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
        app:cardElevation="20dp">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_stock_item_image"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/fragment_stock_item_name"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_stock_item_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:text="A line to string which is long enough to overflow our of container and it has lot of text"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/fragment_stock_item_image"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/fragment_stock_item_image"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_stock_item_image"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/_fragment_stock_frame_line_sep"/>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/_fragment_stock_frame_line_sep"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/fragment_stock_item_name"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/fragment_stock_item_name"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_stock_item_name"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/fragment_stock_item_qty">
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="4.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_stock_item_qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="200"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/_fragment_stock_item_arrow"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/_fragment_stock_frame_line_sep"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/_fragment_stock_frame_line_sep"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/_fragment_stock_frame_line_sep"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/_fragment_stock_item_arrow"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_18dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/fragment_stock_item_qty"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**But now, I this number '200' is taking too much space.**

[image]

Comment: have you tried using ConstraintLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView25"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView66"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView25"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView26"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView25"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView25"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView26"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_black" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

it should be like this
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView25"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView66"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView25"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView25"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView25"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView26"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_black" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView67"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView67"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView26"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView26"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView26" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now, it should be like this
[image: layo]

Comment: Thanks. Please see my modified code. I am facing another problem now.